# PrimeFaces components not updated even after using update attribute

Tags: jsf, primefaces, jsf-2.2

I have 2 pages. Page 1 shows list of users in a datatable with 2 buttons for creating new user and editing existing user. On click of create and edit button both, a pop-up is opened(Page2) with a inputbox and a save button.

The issue that I am facing is if I click create(on Page1), Page2 opens. If I input something in the inputbox name, click cancel and then select an existing row in the datatable on Page1 and click edit,Page2 is opened again and whatever I inputted on create button click is retained and the PrimeFaces component is not updated even though I catch the dialog's onClose event on click of cancel button and reinitialize my view objects.

Page1:

```
<ui:composition template="template.xhtml>"
<ui:define name="center" >
<h:form id="myForm1">
  <h:panelgroup id="panel1">
  <p:datatable ..... />
```

This datatable shows list of users

```
  <p:panelGrid id="buttonMenu1" >
   <p:commandButton id="Create" actionListener="#{myBean1.onCreate}" oncomplete="PF('id2Var').show();" update=":myForm2" />
  </p:panelGrid>
  </h:panelGroup>
</h:form>
</ui:define>
<ui:define name="dialog">
<ui:include src="Page2" />
</ui:define>
</ui:composition>
```

Page2:

```
<p:dialog id="id2" widgetVar="id2Var" >
<p:ajax event="close" listener="#{myBean.onClose}" update=":myForm2" />
<h:form id="myForm2">
  <h:panelgroup id="panel2">
  <p:outputLabel value="Name" />
  <p:inputText id="name" value="myBean.myList.name" />
  <p:panelGrid id="buttonMenu" >
   <p:commandButton id="Save" actionListener="#{myBean.onSave}" update=":myForm2" />
   <p:commandButton id="Cancel" actionListener="#{myBean.resetInput}" update=":myForm2" oncomplete="PF('id2Var').hide();" />
 </p:panelGrid>
</h:panelgroup
</h:form>
</p:dialog>
```

Comment: Why don't you call your resetInput method inside onCreate method?

Comment: It worked. Thanks a lot